# Cypher temp relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to combine / merge a path into a new relationship. The problem is that I'm not interested in storing it but rather return it as a result of a cypher query.

Lets say I have something like this:

```
(a)-[:CALLS_METHOD]->(b)-[:RETURNS_TYPE]->(c)
```

How can I create a temporary relationship like this one:

```
(a)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(c)
```

Only for a result of that particular query, so that I don't have to store it. Because I'm really only interested in the dependency from `a` to `c` and not the details about of that dependency.

Comment: Why not store the relationship anyway?  It won't hurt the performance of anything for the most part.

Comment: In http://jqassistant.org we provide the means of returning "virtual" relationships that aggregate underlying data as part of a concept-query which then can be rendered to graphML to be used e.g. with Gephi or yED

Comment: if you are interested in software-analytics with graphs anyway, we also have a google group on that topic: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/graph-software-analytics

Comment: If the Neo4j Browser supported long running transactions (which it partially does), you could create those relationships as part of a tx but then roll the tx back at the end. If you write your own rendering you can actually do it, but then you can also just support "virtual" relationships.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a relationship from the database that doesn't exist.  The purpose of the queries is to return stuff that does exist.

Perhaps what you're interested in is inferred pairs, rather than a relationship.   Something like:

```
MATCH (a)-[r:CALLS_METHOD|RETURNS_TYPE*]->(b)
RETURN a, "depends on", b
```

Your other alternative is to materialize/save the relationship, and then query for it:

```
MATCH (a)-[r:CALLS_METHOD|RETURNS_TYPE*]->(b)
CREATE a-[newRel:DEPENDS_ON]->b
RETURN newRel;
```

But this has the side-effect of creating it.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with your first statement. The OP is aware of the fact that the searched relation does not exist in the database. However, it seems perfectly fine to create inferred relations on the fly especially for visualization purposes.I currently have a similar problem and I would rather have a real solution to the problem that a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in apoc library to do this: [apoc.create.vRelationship](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.vRelationship/).

Create example data set:

```
CREATE (from:Account), (to:Account)
WITH from, to
CREATE (from)-[:SENT]->(:Payment {amount: 250})-[:RECEIVED]->(to)
CREATE (from)-[:SENT]->(:Payment {amount: 750})-[:RECEIVED]->(to)
```

Perform query with apoc.create.vRelationship function:

```
MATCH (from:Account)-[:SENT]->(p:Payment)-[:RECEIVED]->(to:Account)
RETURN from, to, apoc.create.vRelationship(from,'PAID',{amount:sum(p.amount)},to) as rel;
```

[SEE RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyzRq.png)