# When should inferred relationships and nodes be used over explicit ones?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was looking up how to utilise temporary relationships in Neo4j when I came across this question: [Cypher temp relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645257/cypher-temp-relationship)
and the comment underneath it made me wonder when they should be used and since no one argued against him, I thought I would bring it up here.

I come from a mainly SQL background and my main reason for using virtual relationships was to eliminate duplicated data and do traversals to get properties of something instead.

For a more specific example, let's say we have a robust cake recipe, which has sugar as an ingredient. The sugar is what makes the cake sweet.

Now imagine a use case where I don't like sweet cakes so I want to get all the ingredients of the recipe that make the cake sweet and possibly remove them or find alternatives.

Then there's another use case where I just want foods that are sweet. I could work backwards from the sweet ingredients to get to the food or just store that a cake is sweet in general, which saves time from traversal and makes a query easier. However, as I mentioned before, this duplicates known data that can be inferred.

Sorry if the example is too strange, I suck at making them. I hope the main question comes across, though.

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that the only valid scenario for creating redundant "shortcut" relationships is this:

- Your use case has a stringent time constraint (e.g., average query time must be less than 200ms), *but* your neo4j query -- *despite optimization* -- exceeds that constraint, *and* you have verified that adding "shortcut" relationships will indeed make the response time acceptable.

You should be aware that adding redundant "shortcut" relationships comes with its own costs:

- Queries that *modify* the DB would need to be more complex (to modify the redundant relationships) and also slower.
- You'd always have to add the redundant relationships -- even if actually you never need some (most?) of them.
- If you want to make *concurrent* updates to the DB, the chances that you may [lose some updates and introduce inconsistencies](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/transaction-management/isolation/#transactions-isolation) into the DB would increase -- meaning that you'd have to work even harder to avoid inconsistencies.

NOTE: For visualization purposes, you can use [virtual nodes and relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/virtual/virtual-nodes-rels/#virtual-nodes-rels), which are temporary and not actually stored in the DB.